# portable Sound Edit set up with Macbook and Protools

Tags: pro-tools, macbook-pro

is it possible to have a portable sound edit set up with a Macbook and a pair of decent speakers, to say work on short films of say half an hour ? I am not a Mac user but wondering if I should switch.Since I travel a lot I'd prefer to have a portable small set up to do sound edits for the field recordings I do and also work on short video projects. Any suggestions people? Also, what are the things I would need to have a set up like that? Please suggest :)

Comment: You might want to consider adding an audio interface to the setup, though latest Pro Tools versions should work with all sound card drivers

Comment: @DalvOlan Hi, thanks :) Do you have any idea which model of Macbook should be suitable for such works?

Comment: Here's the requirements for PT 12 http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/Compatibility/Pro-Tools-12-System-Requirements